# How to compare Fraction objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, fractions

I have a use case of equating fractions. Found **fractions** module in Python.

Tried using operators like `<, == and >` and it seems working.

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(5,2) == Fraction(10,4)) # returns True
print(Fraction(1,3) > Fraction(2, 3))  # return False
```

Is this the expected way of doing comparisons?

Could not find anything explicitly specified in the docs.

Can someone confirm this (with a link to the source where it is mentioned)?

Comment: Would you expect something different? Confirm what, exactly?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Yes, 5/2 == 10/4 should be True and 1/3 > 2/3 should be False. What is your expectation? Does it differ? If not, what is that you are wondering about this?

Comment: This is working. I just want to confirm if this is the expected way of comparing fractions objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "expected way of comparing fractions objects"? Those are the comparison operators, what *else* would you expect to use for comparing fractions?

Comment: I was not sure if there exists any class methods or something ( in any parent class).
Anyway got the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation of the fraction module,](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fractions.py) we can see that `__eq__` is defined:

```
def __eq__(a, b):
    """a == b"""
    if type(b) is int:
        return a._numerator == b and a._denominator == 1
    if isinstance(b, numbers.Rational):
        return (a._numerator == b.numerator and
                a._denominator == b.denominator)
    ...
```

And so are `__lt__` and `__gt__`:

```
def __lt__(a, b):
    """a < b"""
    return a._richcmp(b, operator.lt)

def __gt__(a, b):
    """a > b"""
    return a._richcmp(b, operator.gt)
```

So the `==` and `<`/`>` operators will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks.
I did not know that a == b expression invokes '__eq_' method.

Answer (score 2):

Note from the [documentation of Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) that "The Fraction class inherits from the abstract base class numbers.Rational, and implements all of the methods and operations from that class."

Looking at the [documentation of Rational](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Rational), we find that it "Subtypes Real and adds numerator and denominator properties, which should be in lowest terms."

For [Real](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real), we find:

> To Complex, Real adds the operations that work on real numbers.
>
> In short, those are: a conversion to float, math.trunc(), round(),
> math.floor(), math.ceil(), divmod(), //, %, <, <=, >, and >=.

And finally [Complex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Complex):

> Subclasses of this type describe complex numbers and include the
> operations that work on the built-in complex type. These are:
> conversions to complex and bool, real, imag, +, -, *, /, abs(),
> conjugate(), ==, and !=. All except - and != are abstract.

So yes, these operations are defined and documented.